# How to profile a controller action with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-5, profiling

I have a controller action which renders some JSON with the help of a service class, something like:

```
def index
  render json: ServiceClass.search(params)
end
```

The `ServiceClass`'s `.search` method is of the form:

```
def self.search
  new(params).search
end

def search
  {
    key0: value0,
    ...,
    key1: value1,
  }
end
```

where each `value` is a separate `JSON` object obtained through different serializers and helper classes.

I wish to profile the action to get a breakdown of the stack trace to see which methods/queries are taking the longest so I can see where the performance needs improving.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this in Rails 5? The few other solutions I've found on SO are very dated.

Comment: Can we have `ServiceClass's search` method?

Comment: I've edited the question. Adding any more details of the serializers and helper classes won't provide much more useful information.

Comment: If you're looking to find out which search jsons are taking the longest, maybe split them into individual searches? t1 = Time.now, do your search, execution_time = Time.now - t1, puts execution_time

Comment: @Mark I was looking to profile the request, so I can get a breakdown of each method. I think that using the `Time.now` method would be a very time consuming way of doing this.

Comment: Can't you use something like [RubyProf](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof)? If you really want to learn about Rails performance, [this guide](https://www.railsspeed.com/) is very good.